# Adding lambda target role to AWS Eventbridge rule in Cloudformation fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to create an AWS Eventbridge rule with a Lambda function as a target.  I can add the rule and target fine but when I try to set the lambda permissions via `RoleArn` the Cloudformation stack deployment fails with:
`RoleArn is not supported for target arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567890:function:contacts-lambda-consume-new-customer. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxxxx-ec5d-45e8-b45d-xxxxxx; Proxy: null)`

Here is my Cloudformation stack code:

```
  EventRuleNewCustomer: 
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties: 
      Name: new-customer
      EventBusName: myEventBus
      # RoleArn: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:iam::",!Ref "AWS::AccountId", ":role/my-role"] ] #no error but doesn't add the permissions
      Description: "New customer event rule"
      EventPattern: 
        detail-type: 
          - "NewCustomer"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets: 
        - 
          Arn: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:lambda:" ,!Ref "AWS::Region", ":", !Ref "AWS::AccountId", ":function:contacts-lambda-consume-new-customer"] ]
          Id: "NewCustomer"
          RoleArn: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:iam::",!Ref "AWS::AccountId", ":role/my-role"] ]
```

I have tried setting a `RoleArn` on the rule itself which doesn't give an error when the stack is created but also doesn't add the necessary permissions to execute the Lambda.

The work-around I am using is to edit the lambda target in the AWS Eventbridge console.  This seems to do some behind the scenes magic to add the correct permissions for Eventbridge to be able to execute the lambda

Any ideas gratefully appreciated.

Comment: The most frustrating aspect of this is that AWS doesn't output any error message anywhere!!! Still a lot of guessing and trial/error involved with AWS, even in 2022.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> This seems to do some behind the scenes magic to add the correct permissions for Eventbridge to be able to execute the lambda

In case of lambda, the permissions are set using [Lambda's resource-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html).

Thus you should use [AWS::Lambda::Permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) in CloudFormation to allow EventBridge to invoke your function, rather than using `RoleArn`.

So your permissions would be something as the following (just an example):

```
EventBridgeLambdaPermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !GetAtt function.Arn
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: events.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn: !GetAtt EventRuleNewCustomer.Arn
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem :)  I think it was the fact that that the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html lists a RoleArn without saying its not applicable for lambda.  

Also the console has a "Role" column next to the target.  Again I suppose this is not populated when the target  is a lambda

I'll mark your answer as accepted the CF code was exactly right

Comment: @kiwichris No problem. Glad it worked out :-)

Comment: I tried with adding a role and attaching a policy to it with invoke permission but it didn't work. Using your simple permission, it resolved the issue. thanks

Comment: Thanks, this also solved similar problem. 
I had AWS::Events::Rule with RoleArn giving same error. 
Removed the RoleArn then added this solution and it worked.