# AWS eventbridge scheduler in cloudformation: Target needs RoleArn although permissions were attached to lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-event-bridge

I'm new to cloudformation and want to trigger a lambda function with the new event scheduler (AWS::Scheduler::Schedule).

But although I added the permissions (lambda:InvokeFunction with eventbridge principle) to the scheduler, I still need to specify a RoleArn otherwise it throws an error.

That means I have to define a new role for the scheduler target? Which role should I use and how is it done with cloudformation?

Thanks a lot, any help is highly appreciated!
BR Simon

```
#...
  
TriggerStop20dailyCET:
    Type: AWS::Scheduler::Schedule
    Properties:
      Description: Stop RDS and EC2 with Tag 20:00
      Name:
        !Join
        - '-'
        - - Ref: Prefix
          - Ref: Title
          - "20-00_CET"
      FlexibleTimeWindow:
        Mode: FLEXIBLE
        MaximumWindowInMinutes: 1
      ScheduleExpressionTimezone: Europe/Zurich
      ScheduleExpression: "cron(0 20 * * ? *)"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Target:
        Arn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - LambdaInstSchedDispatcher
            - Arn
        #RoleArn: Fn::GetAtt: [ "<which role to use?>", "Arn" ] -> without this key an error is thrown
        Input:  '{"action": "stop", "TagValues":["20:00"]}'

#here I add permissions that "TriggerStop20dailyCET" can trigger "LambdaInstSchedDispatcher" function
PermissionAForEventsToInvokeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaInstSchedDispatcher
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - TriggerStop20dailyCET
          - Arn

#...
```

[permissions example taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053916/adding-lambda-target-role-to-aws-eventbridge-rule-in-cloudformation-fails)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using a permission (this is how it was done with Eventbridge Rules) Schedule uses IAM roles. In other words, instead of permissions you just need to create an IAM role.

Here is one that is working for me:

```
  SchedulerScheduleRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Description: your-description
      RoleName: your-role-name
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - scheduler.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: your-policy-name
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
                Resource:
                  Fn::GetAtt:
                    - LambdaInstSchedDispatcher
                    - Arn
```